# Will dismissal from one graduate school affect me applying to another?

Tags: graduate-school, application

I was dismissed from my Masters program due to bad grades. I also have a mention in my records that say that I might have used last years homework. I did not copy and they had no proof that I copied per se. I couldn't care less about my grades at the time and I deeply regret doing what I did. Is there hope for me in applying to grad schools in the future?

Additionally, I am an international student. Can someone tell me if all this will affect my getting a VISA?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, your transcripts are likely going to be required at time of application to any other program, and you can assume that you will be asked about your poor grades during the application process. That said, you're not the first person to have made bad decisions in the past, so I would definitely still apply.

One thing I would strongly advise *not* doing is attempting to hide the fact you have poor grades by simply not sending the transcript, and pretending it didn't happen. Doing so will almost guarantee career-threatening problems later on when someone finds out what you did (and it won't be hard, there will be a gap of a few years you won't be able to explain, and all the officials at the other university still know that you were there).

I have no idea about the visa.

Comment: It shouldn't affect the visa process itself, but will obviously affect the chances of getting an offer letter which would allow for the visa application.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there hope for me in applying to grad schools in the future?

Yes, but you will need a convincing argument for why graduate school will go better next time than it did the first time you tried it.  It's easy to say "I didn't care about grades and didn't work very hard, but I'll work harder this time," while actually working harder is much more difficult, so vague excuses may be discounted.

You could get lucky and find a school that is happy to give you another chance (perhaps a less prestigious department, which sees potential in you beyond what's typical for their students).  You might also be able to give a more concrete excuse for your past grades (for example, if there were external factors in your life that troubled you last time but won't apply this time).  Otherwise, the best way to demonstrate that things have changed is probably to succeed at something else.  Finding a job and doing well at it can show that you are now more mature and responsible than when you were a student, and successfully taking a few classes part-time can also look good.

So I'd suggest following a two-part strategy.  Try applying again with the best explanations/excuses you can offer, and see whether it works.  If it doesn't, then you should start thinking about longer-term methods to demonstrate that you've changed.